# Why does LLVM AddressSanitizer, but not GCC, give me a memory leak here?

Tags: c, llvm

I'm trying to implement a binary tree in C. I have

```
struct treenode {
  int value;
  struct treenode *left;
  struct treenode *right;
};

typedef struct treenode Tree;

void insert(Tree **tree, int value);
```

but am getting "Direct leak of 24 byte(s) in 1 object(s)". <s>`llvm-symbolizer` won't give me the actual line where the leak occurred, but using `printf` I've traced the execution to the line marked below.</s> EDIT: compiling with `-g` as suggested gives the right line. Running without AddressSantitizer works fine. I don't see where the memory leak is, though: getting rid of `current` and freeing `newNode` seems to do it, but I don't see why either is a leak: `current` is just a pointer to existing allocated memory and `newNode` is about to be inserted into the tree.

**EDIT**: Thank you to everyone who commented/answered. I was misunderstanding how asan reported its results; the leak was because I was not freeing `tree->left` before freeing `tree` in `main`, as commenters suggested.

Compiling with GCC instead of Clang does not produce the error. For Clang I have

```
 % clang -O1 -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -Werror -Wextra binarytree.c
```

and for GCC I have

```
% gcc -O1 -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -Werror -Wextra binarytree.c
```

Clang outputs

```
=================================================================
==24939==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 24 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x49a1bb in __interceptor_malloc (/home/lidavidm/Code/learnc/binarytree+0x49a1bb)
    #1 0x4b795d in insert (/home/lidavidm/Code/learnc/binarytree+0x4b795d)
    #2 0x4b7d54 in main (/home/lidavidm/Code/learnc/binarytree+0x4b7d54)
    #3 0x7fa87fff703f in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x2003f)

Indirect leak of 24 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x49a1bb in __interceptor_malloc (/home/lidavidm/Code/learnc/binarytree+0x49a1bb)
    #1 0x4b7b9c in insert (/home/lidavidm/Code/learnc/binarytree+0x4b7b9c)
    #2 0x4b7d95 in main (/home/lidavidm/Code/learnc/binarytree+0x4b7d95)
    #3 0x7fa87fff703f in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x2003f)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 48 byte(s) leaked in 2 allocation(s).
```

`insert`'s implementation:

```
void insert(Tree **tree, int value) {
  Tree *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Tree)); // asan gives this as the leak
  newNode->value = value;
  newNode->left = NULL;
  newNode->right = NULL;

  if (isEmpty(*tree)) {
    *tree = newNode;
  }
  else {
    Tree *current = *tree;

    while (true) {

      if (value >= current->value) {
        if (!current->right) {
          current->right = newNode;
          return;
        }
        else {
          current = current->right;
        }
      }
      else {
        if (!current->left) {
          current->left = newNode;
          return;
        }
        else {
          current = current->left;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `isEmpty(p)` equals `!p`?

Comment: @Deduplicator yes (`_Bool isEmpty(const Tree *const tree) {
  return !tree;
}`)

Comment: the interesting thing is how little it leaks. do you actually deallocate the root node?

Comment: Perhaps add the other tree-operations, especially delete?

Comment: How does the code that releases the tree structure work?  How is it invoked?

Comment: I also don't see any leaks here. Consider running it under valgrind  (without asan) as an additional check.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath the code stops execution inside the insert method; I don't think it makes sense to deallocate the root node until I'm done with the tree?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not releasing the structure at all, but as far as I can tell the insert method never returns to main - using `printf` asan seems to stop execution inside the second call to insert, which hits the else branch.

Comment: are you intentionally making our lives harder? compile with `-g` and provide code which can be tested.

Comment: Actually, I apologize. I was reading this wrong. It seems like the leak is inside insert, insert does run fully.

Comment: Well, load the code with `printf()` statements so you can see what's up.  You've got an infinite loop with `while (1)`, so it is easy for mistakes to mean that your code never terminates.  I'd prefer a loop termination condition in the `while (…here…)`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I apologize, I'm still not too familiar with C and compiler options. I will investigate further, these comments have been helpful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, you were ultimately right. I was misinterpreting asan's results/how it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is ok, aside from being far too verbose and redundant.
Compare:

```
void insert(Tree **tree, int value) {
    while(*tree)
        tree = value >= tree[0]->value ? &tree[0]->right : &tree[0]->left;
    *tree = malloc(sizeof **tree);
    **tree = (Tree){.value = value};
}
```

So, the leak is obviously somewhere else.

Comment: Note that performing pointer arithmetic (i.e. `tree[0]`, which is `tree + 0`) has undefined behavior when not done on pointers into arrays, which means this code is incorrect unless `tree` points into an array.  This is different than the OP's code, which has no such restriction.  A correct implementation would replace `tree[0]` with `(*tree)`.

Comment: @PatrickNiedzielski: Every object is an array of one.